# How do we change the CSS of the active page in snavbar in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

```
 <ul>
           <BrowserRouter>
           <li ><a class="vote-up-off" ><Icon className=" fa fa-area-chart"/></a></li>
            <li ><a class="vote-up-off" ><Icon className="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x"/></a></li>
            <li ><a class="vote-up-off" ><Icon className="fa fa-line-chart"/></a></li>
            {/* <li><a href="/cluster"><Icon className="fa fa-pie-chart"/></a></li> */}
           
           </BrowserRouter>
           
        </ul>
```

I want to show user which page is active by changing the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using li as link navigations, you can import `NavLink` from react-router-dom and pass a activeClass as a prop, which https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.pathname to get your current path in the browser.[enter link description here](https://w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)